# Converting numbers string to raw in excel similar to cast_to_raw function in Oracle

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, excel-formula

I am new to excel functions and am looking for a way to convert numbers to [raw format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_raw.htm#i997085) similar to output of
`select utl_raw.cast_to_raw('123456') as "raw" from dual;` which is 313233343536

I figured out that it simply appends 3 before every integer of the number.

So,

1 becomes 31

56 becomes 3536

999 becomes 393939

and so on...

I couldn't find anything in the excel predefined functions that would solve my problem. Can someone help with this?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Office 365, the formula can be:

```
=TEXT(A1,REPT("3#", LEN(A1)))
```

This builds a text format `n` number of times based on the length of the number.

[image]

Versions: These functions have been available since at least 2007 based on documentation, so this should work with any version still in use.

Comment: Wow, good thinking and much simpler than my approach!